# How to pass parameters with React-router-dom version 6 useNavigate and typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to send the variable `id` to another page using useNavigate in react-router-dom version 6. Here is what I am trying:

```
const handleSelect = (id: number) => {
    navigate('/Players', {
      userId: id,
    });
  };
```

However I I am getting the error: `Argument of type '{ userId: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigateOptions'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'userId' does not exist in type 'NavigateOptions'.ts(2345)`

I can't find any useful information on NavigateOptions or what type it is looking for. If I remove the parameter `userId` then I can navigate to the `Player` page just fine. It is just the parameter that is causing the problem. What can I do about this issue? Could someone provide some documentation on this?

What would be an example of a parameter that is of type NavigateOptions?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Did you mean to add state to the navigation?
Original:

```
const handleSelect = (id: number) => {
    navigate('/Players', {
      userId: id,
    });
  };
```

Changed to (with state):

```
const handleSelect = (id: number) => {
    navigate('/Players', {
      state: {
        userId: id,
      }
    });
  };
```

Then you can reference `props.location.state.userId` in the `Players` page.

```
// Players Page

import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const location = useLocation();

// get userId
let userId = location.state.userId;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do thank you. However, now when I click on the button the navigation isn't working. Hmmm...

Comment: https://reach.tech/router/api/navigate
That's the API docs you can reference. Maybe it can help you out with the nav button click!

Comment: @JimmyMetz Approach looks good.. But how can we maintain data if user coming back to this page using back button? Is there any other way by which we can maintain state if we navigate to '/Player' page from Back button.

Comment: this does not work with typescript. The question above was explicit about typescript

Comment: It throws error on Typescript. "Property 'props' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)"

Answer (score 2):

In the Players page the "props.location.state.userId" will not work anymore.
Do this in the Players page:

```js
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const location = useLocation();
location.state.userId
```

Comment: this does not work with typescript. The question above was explicit about typescript

Answer (score 1):

When redirecting the user to the `/Players` page you need to send the meta-data in the `state` property of the `options`:

```
const handleSelect = (id: number) => {
    navigate('/Players', {
      state: {
        userId: id,
      }
    });
  };
```

You can then access the state by using `location.state.userId` in the Players page.

**But for Typescript, you'll likely have to cast the `state`:**

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const location = useLocation();
const locationState = (location.state as {userId? : number});

// get userId
let userId = locationState.userId;
```